# Is every single earth part of ALL NEW ALL DIFFERENT Marvel?

Tags: marvel

I know for a fact earth 616 and earth 1610 are in the All-New All-Different Marvel, but are there any other universes?

Comment: The duplicate was not what I was asking

Comment: -I believe what is being asked is whether or not only Earth-616 and Earth-1610 (Ultimate universe) are the only two Earths involved in the All-New, All-Different Marvel event, correct?